# Does shared_ptr's deleter do any synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, shared-ptr, atomic

Everybody who works with multithreaded environments knows you must synchronize between threads to avoid race cases.  I'm particularly interested in synchronization that occurs within a shared_ptr deleter.

In my real situation, I have multiple classes interacting in a way that some of them are aware synchronization is going on, and others are not.  For this example, I have artificially bundled them all onto one object to elucidate the question:

```
class TestObject
{
    public:
        TestObject()
        : mMarked(false)
        { }

        ~TestObject()
        {
            // use of mMarked here indicates that the destructor must be synchronized
            // with any thread that calls mark()
            std::cout << "Object " << (mMarked ? "was marked." : "was not marked.");
        }

        void mark()  { mMarked = true; }

        void someBehaviorThatDoesntNeedSynchronization();

    private:
        bool    mMarked;
};


thread 1:
std::shared_ptr<TestObject> objPtr1 = /* initialize to some instance */;
objPtr1->someBehaviorThatDoesntNeedSynchronization();
objPtr1.reset(); // may call the destructor

thread 2:
std::shared_ptr<TestObject> objPtr2 = /* initialize to the same instance */;
objPtr2->mark();
objPtr2.reset(); // may call the destructor
```

The spec seems to suggest that there is no synchronization at all.  However, this seems very inconsiderate.  It seems like thread 1 is expected to know all synchronization that happened to the object before it can have the privilege of calling a destructor (which could be brutal if the destructor is called during stack unwinding).

Am I missing something?   I know every implementation of shared_ptr actually DOES do synchronization for this very reason, but I can't find anything in the spec to suggest I can trust it.

Is there anything in the spec to suggest that synchronization will occur before a deleter gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur, the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

Comment: That accounts for using member functions on the shared_ptr itself, but does not say anything about using member functions on the object they are pointing to.

Comment: Why would you expect shared_ptr to provide synchronization (or rather, define synchronization behavior) for access to a managed object if you don't use the shared_ptr functions to modify the manage object? You will have to synchronize access to the managed object yourself if this is your implementation strategy.

Comment: Its wishful thinking, really.  The fact that refcount is 0 means there was a PERFECT opportunity to synchronize, the naiive implementation synchronizes by accident, the popular optimized implementation intentionally synchronizes.  Everything lines up except that the spec doesn't choose to call it out.

Comment: It also means you have to be hyper-careful with unwinding the stack for exceptions, because each stack unwind which destroys a shared_ptr has the potential to create a data race WHILE handling exceptional situations! If you have 2 threads that are stack unwinding at once, that's pretty hairy.  To use feeling words, it seems cruel to not let anyone in on the synchronization the shared_ptr already has to do, when they're out on a limb dealing with exceptions on multiple threads.

Comment: @CortAmmon : You are wrong. Two threads will have two stacks with two distinct `shared_ptr` which can be accessed concurrently.

Comment: @MSalters, that is not the issue.  The issue I am having is that I do have two distinct `shared_ptr`, but because there's no synchronization for the deleter, they act less distinct than I feel they should because it is unspecified which thread calls the deleter.  The result is that the synchronization of the deleter must appear in my logic, everywhere, even though the reason for using shared_ptr is to avoid having to pay attention to deleters.

Comment: @CortAmmon: It doesn't matter which thread calls the deleter usually, so shared_ptr defautls to the efficient but unspecified implementation. Your code would be improved by removing the sensitivity to the exact thread calling the deleter.

Answer (score 1):

So there is limited synchronization for `std::shared_ptr`.  A single **instance** of `shared_ptr` cannot be accessed in more than one thread with non-`const` methods (including destructor) safely.

But two `shared_ptr` that both share the same lifetime and data can be each accessed from different threads safely.

An idea of how this is implemented would be that destruction does an interlocked decrement, which decreases the reference counter **and** returns the value it decreased it to atomically.

Then, whichever `~shared_ptr` (or `.reset()`) decreases it to `0` deletes the object.

If we assume that `objPtr1` and `objPtr2` where properly constructed from the same source (possibly with synchronization, or in the same thread before being passed off to workers), and by the time the `.reset()` was called all other `shared_ptr` besides those two had fallen out of scope, then one of the two `.reset()` will destroy the `TestObject`.

Now, technically the value of `mMarked` is **not** synchronized, and as one modified the value in an unsynchronized fashion before the other thread (possibly) read it, the result is undefined behavior.  A practical example of this would be `mMarked` being cached separately by the two CPUs.  In one case, the cached copy is modified.  This is not synchronized with the other cache, who then happens to get the destroy on `.reset()`.

So, in short, access to different `shared_ptr` that refer to the same object itself is safe in more than one thread, but access to the object shared it not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

When the shared_ptr object releases its hold on the pointer, it atomically decrements the reference count. If that reference count is now zero, then the releasing shared_ptr was the only instance referencing that object and it calls the deleter.

So, destruction of your object with shared ownership is synchronized by the atomic operations on the reference count.

Comment: While the implementations I have seen all use atomics as you suggest, the spec curiously avoids any mentioning of atomics or synchronization, other than one reference to data races.

Comment: @Cort: Atomics may wrap native platform implementations, and other parts of the standard library may use that native implementation directly without going through the wrapper.

Comment: @CortAmmon Obviously atomics don't have to be used. You prefer a mutex if you hate efficiency!